# Tehilim HaChida - in the order of the Aleph Bais

Tags: tefilla, aleph-bet-letters, tehilim-psalms, choleh-sick

I recently came across the [Tehilim HaChida](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47723&st=&pgnum=5) which is the entire Tehilim with the Pesukim rearranged in the order of the Aleph Bais by first letter. From the [introduction](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47723&st=&pgnum=3) it seems like it is a special way to pray for someone who is sick or for other issues. Is this practiced anywhere in current times? If not why not?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a website](http://www.jewelrysoftware.net/tehillim/tehillim.html) where you can print out Tehillim in the order of Aleph Bet for a name you want to say Tehillim for. So that's at least one place it is practiced.

Comment: The website is a place?

Comment: @DoubleAA: In the sense of _"this practiced anywhere in current times?"_ . although I could probably chosen a better word

Answer (score -2):

It is used by some for a refuah shelaima to use the persons name as a guide for saying tehillim ,it is brought down in Avodas Hakodesh L'Chida.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that people use it from a work by the same author? If so, I think the question was looking for later sources saying it was accepted by some group and actually used.

Comment: The idea of shimush tehillim goes way back (Teshuvas HaRashba 413) some use it and some prohibit it(Rambam AC 11:12,Shulchan Aruch YD 179:10).

Comment: sam, But the question wasn't about Tehillim in general. It was about this specific form of it.

Comment: Yes which is a form of shimush some will use it and some won't just like segulos.

Comment: sam, Do you have a source that anyone uses this form of shimush?

Comment: @DoubleAA Rav Hai did: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35259&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=

Comment: @ba I was looking for a source that someone used the form of tehillim reading outlined in the question, not tehillim reading in general. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: @DoubleAA, the book in the question does not appear to be by the Chida, but rather it was published to facilitate the advice of the Chida brought in this answer. That such a siddur was published seems to strongly suggest that there were those who followed the Chida's recommendation here.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu Interesting, I did not understand that it was a different author. If someone can find a hebrewbooks link that should settle the matter.

Comment: @DoubleAA Its linked in the question but here is the title page, perhaps I'm misreading it but it does not seem to be published by the Chida himself http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47723&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=

Comment: @Yirmeyahu Oh! Sorry I misunderstood your comment. I thought you were saying the book referenced in this answer was written by someone else. Never mind then. || What you suggested seems like an answer to the question, not a comment to here. In fact, it seems you agree with me that this answer doesn't help much.

Comment: @DoubleAA,  I don't know how we expect to have published confirmation of such a practice more than a siddur designed to facilitate this practice and this answer at least rounds out the issue by showing that there is a source for such a practice.